# Регулярные выражения: поиск ДВУХ слов

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Я использую очень простые регулярные выражения (только начал пользоваться), и, например, могу написать

```
        string src1 = "А в этой строке есть хоть одно слово?";
        string src2 = "А в этой?";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(src1, @"\w*слово\w*"))
            Console.WriteLine(src1);
        if (Regex.IsMatch(src2, @"\w*слово\w*"))
            Console.WriteLine(src2);
```

При этом напечатается первая из двух строк.

Усложним задачу.

Пусть я хочу найти строки, в которых встречаются два известных мне слова (пусть в определеном порядке) одновременно, возможно, разделенные еще чем то.

Я пробую такой паттерн: `\w*хоть\w*слово\w*` - не получается.

Как это принято делать? желательно попроще...

Спасибо!

Comment: https://regex101.com/ - "если вы решаете проблему с помощью регулярных выражений, то у вас две проблемы"

Comment: А зачем тут вообще регулярные выражения? Посмотрите на метод [.IndexOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734218/7286264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string src1 = "А в этой строке есть хоть одно слово?";
    string src2 = "А в этой?";
    string pattern = @"хоть.+слово"; // 2 слова в определенном порядке, но не слитно
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(src1, pattern).Count);
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(src2, pattern).Count);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1
0
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваше внимание к моему примитивному вопросу! но мне кажется, что | -это операция "или". В общем, буду тренироваться дальше.

Comment: @S.H. откройте regex101 и поэкспериментируйте, сайт вам распишет всю логику работы вашего паттерна, я бы сказал даже - очень детально разжует.

Comment: @S.H. перечитал вопрос, исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нашел

Паттерн будет `@"\w*(хоть.*слово)\w*"`

Точка означает любой символ, а звездочка - что он может быть, может не быть, а если быть - то сколько угодно раз.

Почему при этом не срабатывает такой паттерн - `@"\w*(хоть\w*слово)\w*"` - я не понимаю...

Comment: `\w` не работает, потому что кириллица, он только работает на множестве `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, и снова открыть regex101, написать в паттерн `\w` и почитать, что справа написано. - _\w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])_

Comment: `.*` - 0 и больше, `.+` - 1 и больше, ваш паттерн среагирует даже на `хотьслово`